# Servlet context path and registrations are correct, but mapping still does not work. How shall I debug/fix it?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

I'm not an experienced j2ee developer, so excuse me in advance if I'm missing something completely basic or obvious.

I'm using Tomcat 7.
Project is deployed to the tomcat instance with `tomcat7-maven-plugin` plugin and `redeploy` goal in `pom.xml`. Build works without errors, the only weird thing is that it adds `#` sign at the end of `.war` name, like `mytest#.war`.

Servlet code is extremely simple: it just prints debug info and responds with a string on GET requests.

Init part works fine. It prints following mapping info(I guess it is correct):

```
Path=/mytest/                      //this is context path
StupidServlet[/stupid]             //this line and following ones are registrations
jsp[*.jsp, *.jspx]
default[/]
```

However, when I try to request `http://localhost:8080/mytest/stupid`, it displays 404 message from tomcat. Index.jsp is also 404, and root returns some invalid redirect(at least firefox tells that).

My `web.xml` file is taken from some answers here to correspond to Servlet 3.0 standard:

`<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0"/>`

Servlet code:

```
@WebServlet(name = "StupidServlet", loadOnStartup = 1, urlPatterns = {"/stupid"})
public class StupidServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        System.out.print("This is STUPID INIT FROM SERVLET!!!!");
        Map servlets =  getServletContext().getServletRegistrations();
        System.out.println("\n===REGISTRATIONS==="+getServletContext().getServletContextName());
        System.out.println("Path="+getServletContext().getContextPath());

        for(String key:servlets.keySet()){
            ServletRegistration servlet = servlets.get(key);
            System.out.println(""+key+servlet.getMappings());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("STUPID REQUEST IS DONE");
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        resp.getOutputStream().println("My name is Stupid Servlet");
        resp.flushBuffer();

    }
}
```

Comment: The servlet code posted so far would cause an infinite loop. Did you really got 404? Debugging is rather easy: run a debugger and put a breakpoint on `doGet()` method and track the code execution. If you have no clue how to use a debugger, then fall back to placing poor man's `System.out.println()` lines at strategic locations printing variables of interest.

Comment: It is really 404. I fixed that stupid call of super.service, but it really never comes to it.

Comment: The fix would cause a 405 error if the servlet was really been hit. By the way, that you keep calling everything "stupid" is also not really motivating/respectful in order to get answers. It's not the Java/Servlet API who's being wrong.

Comment: It's obvious that `doGet` is not being called, but I don't see any reason for that. You can see that I've provided a lot of context info , not only servlet code. Your answer 'Your code is not executed!' is not very helpful. Can you see question title? As for my identifiers, they are not related to java api, I'm not here to blame java or offend stackoverflow users. Those names are related to my code. Obviously something in my code is stupid because it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've given up in one step before finding an answer.

This debug output line

```
Path=/mytest/                     //this is context path
```

holds the explanation. **Context path shall not end with trailing `/`.**
This is also a reason for `#` sign at the end of deployed war(seems that symbols unsupported in file names are converted to #). However, I'm not sure why trailing `/` is not ignored. It looks to me like a defect.

So I changed `tomcat7-maven-plugin` configuration, replacing `/mytest/` with `/mytest`:

```
<configuration>
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
    <server>tomcat7</server>
    <path>/mytest</path>
</configuration>
```

And it fixed the mapping problem.

Now printing context path results in

```
Path=/mytest                     //this is context path
```

Thanks to  @BalusC, I know how to deal with `405` which I've received after config change.